# Browser appends underscore to dynamic loaded JS

Tags: javascript, performance, browser

When i inject a Javascript `<script>`-tag via javascript. All browsers append automatically a query parameter `_` (underscore) with the current timestamp to the url during the download. This is not a nice behavior, because the browser can not cache the script anymore.

Eg:

For `<script src="/dyn/generated.js"/>` all browsers load `/dyn/generated.js?_=1489660571375`

Is there a way to prevent this, so the browser do cache my js file?

---

**Solution** (thanks to Jaromanda)

Append the script with javascript function its self. Do not use jQuery!
After switching to native functions the underscores are gone.

```
    var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
    scriptTag.type = "text/javascript";
    scriptTag.src = "http://*.js";
    document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);
```

Comment: none of my browsers do that to script tags ... you're creating those tags using some jquery stuff maybe? as you used the word "dynamic" in the question, I'm assuming the script tags are generated dynamically - and most numpties use jQuery for that

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution** (thanks to Jaromanda)

Append the script with javascript function its self. Do not use jQuery!
After switching to native functions the underscores are gone.

```
    var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
    scriptTag.type = "text/javascript";
    scriptTag.src = "http://*.js";
    document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);
```